# Sieve improvement for Fermat's factorization method

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, prime-factorization

I been reading the wiki article about, [Sieve improvement for Fermat's factorization method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method#Sieve_improvement).

And I don't understand the mode 16 example, I understand why $a^2$ must be $9$. But why $a$ must be $3$ or $5$ or $11$ or $13$ modulo $16$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^2 \equiv 9 \mod 16$ then $a$ must be odd.  But if $a \in\{1,7,9,15\} \mod 16$ then $a^2 \equiv 1 \neq  \mod 16$.

Comment: Why if $a \in\{1,7,9,15\} \mod 16$ than $a^2 \equiv 1$?

Comment: @Ilya $\ (8n\pm1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{\!16}\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque can you please give me a reference to read an explanation for your comment?

Comment: @Ilya $\ (8n\pm1)^2 - 1 = 64n^2\pm 16n\,$ is divisible by $\,16\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque sorry I don't get it. I don't understand what are you trying to say. I don't understand what is the connection between $a \mod n$ and $a^2 \mod n$

Comment: @Ilya $\ a\in \{1,7,9,15\}\,\Rightarrow\, a\equiv \pm1\pmod 8\,\Rightarrow\, a^2\equiv 1\pmod{16}\,$ by my prior comments. $\ $

Answer (score 0):

[Modular Improvement To Fermat's Factorization Method] If you take N=XY and cast it into a modular form say, $$Bz+r=(Bx+a)(By+b)$$ where $r$ is congruent to $ab$ mod $B$ (there will be $\phi(B)$ possibilities assuming $r$ and $B$ are co-prime.)   The modular form can be reduced to $$Bxy+ax+by+m=z$$ where $m$ equals the floor of $ab$ divided by $z$.  Now apply a change of variables to $x$ and $y$, let $x=t+s$, and $y=t-s$.  You will arrive at $$B(t^2-s^2)+(a+b)t+(a-b)s+m=z$$ Trivially if $B=1$ this is Fermat.  If $B>1$ you get a reduced search area and the structure of the reduced residue system to guide your efforts.  There are many many interesting algorithms related to this idea which I have come to call a modular improvement of Fermat's Method.  It is more straightforward than it even seems at first glance.

Cheers.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599) to improve your answer.